Solution of non-homogeneous wave equation in finite domain.
Let $u(x,y)$ be the solution of the non-homogeneous wave equation $$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}- \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}=sin(x)sin(2t), 0< x< \pi, t>0$$
$$u(x,0)=0, u_t(x,0)=0$$ $$u(0,t)=0, u(\pi,t)=0.$$ Then the value of $$u(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2})=---------?$$ I tried it by assuming $w(x,t)=u(x,t)-v(x,t)$, where $v(x,t)$ is particular solution of $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}- \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}=sin(x)sin(2t)$ and  $$\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2}- \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial t^2}=0, 0< x< \pi, t>0$$
$$w(x,0)=-v(x,0), w_t(x,0)=-v_t(x,0)$$ $$w(0,t)=-v(0,t), w(\pi,t)=-v(\pi, t).$$ But it becomes more difficult. How to solve it in less time? Thank you.

Hint. Use the ansatz $u(x,t)=f(t)\sin(x)$. It satisfies the boundary conditions $u(0,t)=u(\pi,t)=0$ and, when substituted in the wave equation, yields the ODE
$$
f''(t)+f(t)=-\sin(2t). \tag{1}
$$
Now find the solution to $(1)$ that satisfies the initial conditions $f(0)=0, f'(0)=0.$ I leave this simple task to you.

this solves my problem. Thank you.

I think ODE is $f''- f= sin(2t)?$

Equation $(1)$ is correct: $(\partial_{x}^2-\partial_{t}^2)f(t)\sin(x)=-f(t)\sin(x)-f''(t)\sin(x)$.

Using the Laplace transform we have
$$
U_{xx}(s,x)-s^2U(s,x) = \frac{2\sin x}{s^2+2^2}
$$
solving this ode regarding $x$ we have
$$
U(s,x) = c_1(s)e^{sx}+c_2(s) e^{-sx} -\frac{2\sin x}{(s^2+1)(s^2+4)} 
$$
applying the boundary conditions regarding $x$ we obtain $c_1(s) = c_2(s) = 0$ and finally
$$
u(t,x) = \frac 23\sin t(\cos t-1)\sin x
$$

Thank you. actually, in our syllabus, Laplace is not there. Is it possible without Laplace?
